# agergar función a controladora en laravel 6

Tags: laravel

Tengo la siguiente situación: necesito crear una función personalizada en mi controladora para hacer un cambio de password, de una lista de usuario que tengo creada pero me sucede que cuando la llamo me envia un **error 404**. A contuniación les dejo el codigo que tengo desarrollado hasta ahora para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Gracias.

Función que trato de agregar para cargar la vista de cambio de password.

```
/**
 * Show the views change password 

 * 

 * @param init $id

 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response

 */

public function changepw($id)

{

    $datosUser = User::join('model_has_roles', 'users.id', 'model_id')
        ->join('roles', 'roles.id', 'role_id')
        ->select('users.name as unames', 'roles.name as rnames', 'users.*')

        ->findOrFail($id);

    return view('user.changepw', compact('datosUser'));

}
```

Ruta creada para llamar la función de **changepw**

```
Route::get('User/changapw', 'UserController@changepw')->name('User.changepw');
```

Lista de rutas en laravel donde se puede apreciar la ruta creada.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                         | Name               | Action                                                                 | Middleware                                                                                                                         |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                           |                    | Closure                                                                | web                                                                                                                                |
|        | POST      | User                        | User.store         | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store                              | web,role:administrador                                                                                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | User                        | User.index         | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index                              | web,role:administrador                                                                                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | User/changapw               | User.changepw      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@changepw                           | web,role:administrador                                                                                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | User/create                 | User.create        | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@create                             | web,role:administrador                                                                                                             |
```

Modo en que llamo la función de la vista.

```
 <td><a href="{{url('/User/'.$end->id.'/changepw' )}}" class="btn btn-link" ><span data-feather="lock"></span></a></td>
```

Comment: tu ruta es `href="{{url('/User/'.$end->id.'/changepw' )}}"` que traducida es `href="http://localhost/User/1/changepw"` por lo que debes pasar el `id` en medio en `web.php` quedaria asi: `Route::get('User/{id}/changapw', 'UserController@changepw')->name('User.changepw');` saludos!

Comment: Hola hice lo que me comenta pero aun me persiste el error: asi me quedo. `Route::get('User/{id}/changapw', 'UserController@changepw')->name('User.changepw');`

Comment: a que ruta te envia al darle click??

Comment: A esta ruta `http://127.0.0.1:8000/User/1/changepw`

Comment: dale un dd($id) en el controlador y comenta el resto a ver si llega, si todo sale bien debes revisar tu query verifica que tengas el `APP_DEBUG=true` en el `.env`

Comment: para entender lo que me comenta que lo que me dice es que cree una función sola en la controladora y cree una ruta para ella solo y veo si esta llegando.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100448/discussion-between-yoel-rodriguez-and-bryro).